# Resize windows as though there were separators between the windows

Tags: windows-7, windows

I often tile my windows. I also often find that I don't want to split the windows right down the middle. Perhaps I'd like one window to take up 5/8ths of the screen and other windows to divide the remaining half.

It's easy enough to create such a layout with a program like [GridMove](http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html) (which I already use). However, resizing your windows on the fly is time consuming because you have to resize *every* window that is currently visible.

I'm looking for a solution that would let me resize one window and the other automatically resizes (akin to resizable separators).

Here's an image of what this would look like:

Initially, I have my windows located like so (the red line shows the divide between the windows I am going to resize):

[image: Tiled windows]

I want to be able to drag the left side of the Firefox window with the other windows adjusting in size accordingly:

[image: Resized windows]

In fact, the particular combination of Windows that are open shows a particularly common use case: the website I am viewing (this one) does not display properly on narrower resolutions, so I'd have to resize the window in order to view the entire site.

Is there a program that would allow this kind of resizing?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 has the bare minimum when it comes to tiled window support (Windows 8 is only slightly better). What you are looking for is a tiling window manager to replace the window manager which comes with Windows. This is generally considered to be a security risk because it means overwriting some core Windows files. There is a wiki article devoted to the topic of what [tiled window managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager#3rd_party_addons) are available.